# cron to anacron migration process

Tags: cron, shell, rhel5, rhel6

I have a script that I want to run nightly on my lab's RHEL 5 and 6 workstations, so I'm deploying the script to each system's /etc/cron.daily/ directory and making it executable there.  But some workstations may not be powered on at the time when cron.daily runs, so I believe anacron might be more appropriate for this purpose.

How would I go about converting this simple cron set-up to use anacron instead of cron?

It seems that /etc/anacrontab already runs the scripts in /etc/cron.daily as well:

```
# /etc/anacrontab: configuration file for anacron

# See anacron(8) and anacrontab(5) for details.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
# the maximal random delay added to the base delay of the jobs
RANDOM_DELAY=45
# the jobs will be started during the following hours only
START_HOURS_RANGE=3-22

#period in days   delay in minutes   job-identifier   command
1   5   cron.daily      nice run-parts /etc/cron.daily
7   25  cron.weekly     nice run-parts /etc/cron.weekly
@monthly 45 cron.monthly        nice run-parts /etc/cron.monthly
```

Are there any steps needed to make sure the workstations will execute the script in a more or less reliable fashion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your workstations are not reliably powered on then anacron is the tool for the job as the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/8/anacron) says

> ...it does not assume that the machine
>          is running continuously.  Hence, it can be used on machines that aren’t
>          running 24 hours a day, to control regular jobs as daily,  weekly,  and
>          monthly jobs.

Further down it says how

> For each job, Anacron checks whether this job has been executed in  the
>          last  n  days,  where  n is the period specified for that job.  If not,
>          Anacron runs the job’s shell command, after waiting for the  number  of
>          minutes specified as the delay parameter.

SO it would appear that all you have to do is add suitable entries to your [anacrontab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/anacrontab) file.

Comment: My reading of the default anacrontab file above is that it runs all scipts in /etc/cron.daily  (`nice run-parts /etc/cron.daily`) .  In this case just placing my shell script in the workstation's /etc/cron.daily directory and making it executable should suffice then?

Comment: Probably yes but that's easily tested.